# How to use @break in ternary operatory to break foreach loop in laravel blade file?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing project in Laravel. I have foreach loop in blade file I want to break foreach loop when condition satisfied, but here in this case I have used ternary operator and in this operator I want to break my foreach loop.
Here is my blade file,

```
@foreach($user->preference_attributes as $attributes)

<tr>
            <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.access.users.tabs.content.overview.location') }}</th>
            <td>{!!($attributes->name == 'location') ? $attributes->pivot->value @break : '' !!}</td>
        </tr>

@endforeach
```

I have done like this but its not working. I am not getting how to break this with ternary operator. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No here I want to break this loop with ternary operator not using if else

Comment: Try changing this `$attributes->pivot->value @break` to just `break`

Comment: I tried this but not working

Answer (score 1):

you can not do this

```
{!!($attributes->name == 'location') ? $attributes->pivot->value @break : '' !!}
```

in your error case, `blade` is converted to a `PHP` file, there is a very obvious syntax error here, that is why you have to use `PHP` syntax in `{{ }}` or `{!! !!}`

[image]

**This is not the real reason, I take back these words, it just because PHP grammar limit that cannot be written like that**

> **impossible to achieve use in ternary operator**
>   when the code converted to
>   `<?php echo e($attributes->name == 'location' ? $attributes->pivot->value : ''); ?>` 
>   *ternary operator is a parameter of  function `e()`, consider this error example
>   `functionName( 'someStringParameter'; break; )`
>   Do you find the problem?*

try this

```
<tr>
    <th>{{ trans('labels.backend.access.users.tabs.content.overview.location') }}</th>
    <td>
        @if($attributes->name == 'location')
            {!! $attributes->pivot->value !!}
            @break
        @endif
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Then is it like, I cant use break in ternary operator?

Comment: yes I got it... This might be a case then. Lets see if I get any solution to this orelse I will upvote your answer then

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `if` method？

```
@if($attributes->name == 'location')
{{ $attributes->pivot->value}} @break
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want to use ternary operator

Comment: I think it should be no effect you want,If you don't output value,you can use @break($attributes->name = 'location').

Comment: Actually form contains too much list items and thats why I didnt wanted to use if else

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this not sure

```
{{ $attributes->name == 'location' ? $attributes->pivot->value @break : '' }}
```